# (Perl) Trying to write a foreach statement with a simple array. Confused with the formatting

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I'm a beginner in programming, this is my first language. And in my class we are using a slightly out of date book to learn with (Book copyrighted '02). Doubt this would affect you helping me much, but worth noting.

**The problem**

I don't know how to format a simple foreach statement using/combined with an array. I'm getting mixed up and my book doesn't provide examples. I'm trying to get it so the Uses/Primary_Uses are shown when the user checks multiple checkboxes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#c04ex5.cgi - creates a dynamic Web page that acknowledges
#the receipt of a registration form
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
use CGI qw(:standard -debug);
use strict;

#declare variables
my ($name, $serial, $modnum, $sysletter, $primary_uses, $use, @primary_uses, @uses);
my @models = ("Laser JX", "Laser PL", "ColorPrint XL");
my @systems = ("Windows", "Macintosh", "UNIX"); 
my @primary_uses = ("Home", "Business", "Educational", "Other");


#assign input items to variables
$name = param('Name');
$serial = param('Serial');
$modnum = param('Model');
$sysletter = param('System');
@primary_uses = param('Use');



#create Web page
print "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Juniper Printers</TITLE></HEAD>\n";
print "<BODY><H2>\n";
print "Thank you , $name, for completing \n";
print "the registration form.<BR><BR>\n";
print "We have registered your Juniper $models[$modnum] printer, \n";
print "serial number $serial.\n";
print "You indicated that the printer will be used on the\n";
print "$systems[$sysletter] system. <BR>\n";
print "The primary uses for this printer will be the following:\n";

#The part I'm having trouble with.     
foreach $use (@primary_uses) {
print "$use [@use]<BR>\n";
} 

print "</H2></BODY></HTML>\n";
```

My naming of variables might be a bit off, I was getting desperate and making sure I declare more than I should.

Comment: Do you just want to print all the elements in array @primary_uses?

Comment: You should reduce your code to only show your problem area. This is far too much code. Also, you should always `use warnings`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the etiquette of posting for coding problems. I will remember to only post the part I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to print a simple list of items, you should just use the `$use` variable:

```
foreach $use (@primary_uses) {
    print "$use<BR>\n";
}
```

Note that this will also remove the fatal error that comes from not declaring `@use`. Perhaps that was also a point of confusion for you. `$use` and `@use` are two completely different variables, despite having the same name.

Note that you can print a list with the `CGI` module very easily:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
print $cgi->li(\@primary_uses);
```

Outputs the list interpolated in a list html entity, like so:

```
<li>Home</li> <li>Business</li> <li>Educational</li> <li>Other</li>
```

**Some other pointers:**

Note that it is a good idea to declare your variables in the smallest scope possible

```
foreach my $use (@primary_uses) {   # note the use of "my"
    print "$use<BR>\n";
}
```

That also goes with the other variables. A good idea is to declare them right as you initialize them:

```
my $name = param('Name');
```

Then people who read your code don't have to scan backwards in the file to see where the variable has "been" before.

Note that you should never, ever use the content of data from a web form without sanitizing it first, because it is a huge security risk, especially when you print it. It allows a web user to execute arbitrary code on your system.

You should know that `for` and `foreach` are aliases for the same function.

Also, you should always, always use warnings:

```
use warnings;
```

There really is no good reason to ever not turn warnings on.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach my $myuse (@primary_uses) {
    print $myuse;
}
```

You need to declare the variable.

Comment: You have the right answer, just the wrong explanation.

Comment: Right, $use is declared as a scalar, not as an array.

Comment: Nope... `$use` and `@use` are two different variables, and its perfectly legal to use the same name. And also he declares `@uses`, not `@use` (which also leads to a strict-error)

Comment: In the foreach loop she used @use which is not declared - this would cause an error since use strict is set

Comment: Yes, she could have declared both but she didn't

Comment: I suspect she did not know that `@use` is a different variable.